# How I can get the calling methods in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

I need a way to know the name of calling methods in C#.

For instance:

```
private void doSomething()
{
// I need to know who is calling me? (method1 or method2).

// do something pursuant to who is calling you?
} 

private void method1()
{
 doSomething();
}

private void method2()
{
 doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Under what circumstances would you need to know that?

Comment: This smells like  bad programming practise, Please tell us why you want to do that? ;-)

Comment: Pass a parameter to the doSomething() function depending on which one calls it.

Comment: Yes, this is usually not a good idea

Comment: I can't think of a situation where this was a good idea.

Comment: I can think of a situation where this is a good idea - if you have shared code responsible for some cross cutting concern, e.g. logging, you might want this information to specialize the output from the shared code - I use this practice in service call logging, a utility function sets up security and logging for the service call and uses the identity of the calling function for both logging and a check on security access rights

Comment: @Mark: as I say in my answer, the best practice would be to not have the code know about the callers, but rather to have the code know about the the different specialized scenarios - and have the caller say which scenario is desired.

Comment: Realize this is 3 yrs old, but I agree with Mark. Came across this question because of one such scenario. Have a Windows service that times out on first attempt to start 70%+ of the time. After getting "service failed to start in a timely manner...." I immediately click Start again and it always works. Trying to put logging in various places in numerous classes. Don't want to create an EventLog object in every class. Have a "central" one that accepts "message" to log and adds other info. Want calling code to be short as possible, i.e. should not need to identify itself.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

from http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name/

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

// get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

Comment: I think in release builds you can't depend on this since the jit compiler could optimize code and so the name could be different.

Comment: But How I can get preveous method call. changing GetFrame() give you all methods in calling stack.

Comment: That's what the (1) is for.  You must use [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] to ensure your method doesn't get inlined.

Comment: True, however extracting stack traces for any reason other than debugging or logging should be avoided.  This can cause horrible performance.

Comment: for me, i use this as a quick debug helper to know w/c methods called a particular method.

Comment: Some people say this is bad for performance. Is it true?

Comment: Performance is probably worse, but in my case (called max ~150 times in a row), I could not even measure the difference. BUT, I cannot underline enough what Stormenet/Hans Passant said about not depending on this in release builds. I spent a woeful 2 days of searching for a bug, then finding this problem. It's about as cloudy as it can get, because you can add nonsensical code that will prevent the inlining, and also your code will work in debug mode.

Answer (score 7):

You almost certainly don't want to do this. A caller should never know who is calling it. Instead, the difference between the two callers should be abstracted into a parameter, and passed into the method being called:

```
private void doSomething(bool doItThisWay)
{
    if (doItThisWay)
    {
        // Do it one way
    }
    else
    {
        // Do it the other way
    }
}

private void method1()
{
    doSomething(true);
}

private void method2()
{
    doSomething(false);
}
```

This way, if you add a method3, it can either doSomething one way or the other, and doSomething won't care.

Comment: You might want to do that only if you are outputting some debug information

Comment: @Andrey: debugging and such is always a special case. If the OP was interested in debugging, he should probably have said so. Outside of debugging (tracing, performance instrumentation, etc), this is not a good idea.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that's not a right answer. You don't get the method name

Comment: @John Saunders He just means that this is more appropriate as a comment than an answer, since it doesn't give him an actual answer to his original question.