# Get referring method in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get the referring method in vb.net.

e.g. I have 1 generic method (sendMail) that handle's emails, any other method can call this. I want sendMail to *log* an entry to the database when it sends an email. In this *log* i want the name of method that calls sendMail. I can do it by passing paramaters but I would like to know if sendMail can access the name of the method that calls it.

I found this article that works great in vs
[Is it possible to get the referring method in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715216/is-it-possible-to-get-the-referring-method-in-vb-net)
but unfortunately i'm working in a proprietary application and their IDE and the output I get from StackFrame is 'ExecuteAction at offset 1438 in file:line:column :0:0 '.  I think it might be because the StackFrame used in example by Jon works in debug mode not release. (MSDN said something about debug mode but i'm not 100% sure here)

Is there another way of getting the calling method name?
Or am I using StackFrame incorrectly?

Cheers in advance.

dno

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string GetStackTrace()
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
        StackFrame[] frames = st.GetFrames();

        return frames[1].GetMethod().Name.ToString();
    }
```

give it a try:
this method will most likely return the name of its caller, with a few adjustment, you cant tweak it to nest back by increasing the index of the frames array.
good luck

Comment: pardon my ignorance. I'm a DBA. not a .NET dev. This code example is for c#? is that correct?

Comment: you're completely true, the namespaces are alike in both language it wont make much of a difference, if you have any further questions am ready.   
i might forget to mention you should include System.Diagnostics   
VB: imports System.Diagnostics   
C#: using System.Diagnostics   
regards