# How get name of method in the method

Tags: c#

I have a method. I want to check a condition and 
if result of my condition is true throw new exception.
I need to name of method for message exception. For example :

```
public void MyMethod(Notifier not)
{ 
    if(not.HasValue())
        throw new Exception("MyMethod_name : " + not.Value);
}
```

How get name of method in the method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Calling function name from Called function in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310145/get-calling-function-name-from-called-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method

Comment: if you are using .net 4.5 beta +, you can use [CallerInformation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach avoids the stack issues:

```
public void MyMethod(Notifier not)
{ 
    if(not.HasValue())
    {
        string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        throw new Exception(methodName + ": " + not.Value);
    }
}
```

[But note that there may occasionally be unexpected results: for example, small methods or properties are often inlined in release builds, in which case the result will be the caller's method name instead.]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you looking for?

```
new StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().Name
```

but again playing with stack means performance hit if misused.

**OR** are you looking for this - http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-method-names/

**OR** http://heifner.blogspot.co.nz/2006/12/logging-method-name-in-c.html

**OR** have a look here nice notes - [Get Calling function name from Called function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310145/get-calling-function-name-from-called-function-in-c-sharp)

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MyMethod(Notifier not)
{ 
  StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame();
  MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();

  if(not.HasValue())
      throw new Exception("MyMethod_name : " + methodBase.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection you can get the method name.....By using the powerful reflection facilities in the framework, you can invoke the method. This involves the `System.Reflection` namespace and the`GetMethod` method.

For implementation of Reflection, take a reference to this link......

http://www.dotnetperls.com/getmethod