# How to get the parent method name?

Tags: c#, reflection, nunit

I'm using writing web tests with NUnit and Selenium WebDriver.
At the end of each test, I would like to get a screenshot of the browser and save the image.
I would like the image name to be the same as the `Test` name.
But I'm having trouble to get the test method name.

Here's is the test method:

```
[Test]
public void AbcTest_ShouldPass()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
}
```

here's the `TearDown` which runs after each `Test`:

```
[TearDonw]
[MethodImpl(MethoImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public void TestCleanupNunit()
{
    var methodName = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        methodName.Add(i.ToString() + " is " + new StackTrace(i, true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name);

}
```

but when I look at the `methodName`, I couldn't find `AbcTest_ShouldPass`.

```
0 is TestCleanupNUnit
1 is InvokeMethod
2 is UnsafeInvokeInternal
3 is Invoke
4 is Invoke
5 is InvokeMethod
6 is InvokeMethod
7 is RunTearDown
8 is RunTest
9 is RunTest
10 is RunRepeatedTest
11 is RunTestInContext
12 is Run
13 is RunAllTests
14 is RunSuite
15 is RunSuiteInContext
16 is Run
17 is Run
18 is RunAllTests
19 is RunSuite
20 is RunSuiteInContext
21 is Run
22 is RunAllTests
23 is RunSuite
24 is RunSuiteInContext
25 is Run
26 is RunAllTests
27 is RunSuite
28 is RunSuiteInContext
29 is Run
```

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310145/get-calling-function-name-from-called-function-in-c-sharp), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunit Framework provides CurrentContext which is member of NUnit.Framework.TestContext.

TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name would return the name of the test under execution and TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName would return fully qualified name starting from namespace's name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because your test does not call the test teardown.  The test runner calls your test case and then the test tear down in turn.  In other words, your test case method call is in a different branch of the stack trace than the tear down.

You would need to cache your method's name in your test fixture somewhere.  Maybe a private member variable and you set that variable in each test case's method.  That's not very elegant, but that's the only way I can think of at the moment.

Comment: That's similar to what I did before. I hope there's a better way. But thanks for your additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtunately, the Setup and Teardown methods of a unit test are not run as part of a synchronous call stack, but are instead handled by the test engine. as such the callstack as observed from the Teardown method will not contain the methods run as part of a test.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having this be in the test tear down, you could just have a private method which saves the screenshot that you call at the end of each test.  Then your stack trace would contain the test case method as you are expecting.

I agree that this method is not perfect because you have to remember to add it to each test case, but at least it is generic and doesnt involve method names in hard coded strings.