# How to get caller methods name?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, envdte

Is there a way to get all caller of C# method ie:

```
public string Caller(string str)
{      
  Customer cust = new Customer();
  cust.Firstname = "Peter";
  cust.LastName = "Beamer";
  string t = getName(cust);
  return t;
}

private string getName(Customer customer)
{
  return customer.Firstname +" "+ customer.LastName;
}
```

would return: Caller.

All I can get now is method body text using **EnvDTE.CodeFunction**. Maybe there is a better way to achieve it than trying to parse this code.

**Note: I don't want to get current method's calling method name. I want that If I give name of the method then It will return passed method's calling methods name.**

Comment: *What* would return `Caller`? It's not clear what your context is here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the method that called the current method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: @Gray : I don't want to get current method's caller method name.  I want that If I give method name than my code should return passed method's caller. In my given example, If I give 'getName' as method name then my code should return 'Caller' .

Comment: @ChandniShah why are you passing `Customer` to `getName` if what you want it to return is "Caller"? Try `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`, instead of `getName` in `Caller` function.

Answer (score 6):

```
new StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().Name
```

Note that in release builds the compiler might inline the method being called, in which case the above code would return the caller of the caller, so to be safe you should decorate your method with:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310148/1714342

Comment: Just beware of the performance impact. Do not use this in production code. If you think you actually need it, take a look at PostSharp

Comment: @SteveB, I was going to say the exact same thing!

Comment: @wudzik : This will return current method's caller name. I want that If I give method name than my code should return passed method's caller.

Comment: @ChandniShah so you want to new StackFrame(2,true).GetMethod().Name?

Comment: @wudzik: I don't think it will work. I am developing visual studio plugin from which I am analyzing the code of project. So from plugin code if I pass name of some class from my host project. it should give me caller methods name.

Comment: @ChandniShah now I get it, it's more complicated then :D this topic is more related to your task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490025/c-sharp-reflection-and-find-all-references

Answer (score 5):

Not really positive I understand what you're asking since no one seems sure what should return "Caller"... but, perhaps the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) might be of some help?

Answer (score 4):

While it is certainly possible to do it using `StackFrame` as wudzik points out, why would you need to do this?

This is a design smell. If your code has to have knowledge about its caller, something is wrong with your design. Every such dependency should be abstracted out of your class model.

Comment: I think it could potentially be helpful for debugging, but I agree that it very much seems like something that your production code should not use or depend on.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in code, you can examine the entire stack trace at any time. It would be unnecessary to put such dependencies in code, even for debugging purposes... The code would quickly become unreadable and unmaintainable (very hard to change!)

Comment: That makes sense; I don't think it belongs in code for the long term in anyway. It definitely seems like something you would do in a language that does not include the powerful debugger that comes with Visual Studio. It just sort of has the feel of a temporary 'Debug.WriteLine' that you throw in to help you understand the flow better. More of an educational/novice tool for someone not yet comfortable with the debugger. There may be some truly legitimate use with profiling/optimizing, but I can't come up with a great example.

Comment: @RoyDictus: my production code is not dependent on this. I am developing one visual studio plugin in which I have to parse the code.