# Find Invoker Method Name

Tags: c#, .net

I have a structure like below:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string SendError(string Message){

         //which method called me

         return Message;

    }
}


public class TypeAClass : BaseClass
{
    public static TypeAClass Instance { get; set;}

    public void TestToTest()
    {
         SendError("Test Message");
    }
}
```

Can I get the method name that calls the SendError() in the SendError method. For example, in this scenario it should give me the name TestToTest()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the method that called the current method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: Pay attention to the caveats of using StackFrame.GetMethod, as described in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/172015/832377)... specially inline optimizations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a feature of C# 5:

You can declare a parameter of a function as a caller info:

```
public string SendError(string Message, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine(callerName + "called me.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
String callingMethodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StackFrame caller = (new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()).GetFrame(0);
string methodName = caller.GetMethod().Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171974/635634) of the duplicate question:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

// get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

Or more brief:

```
new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name
```