# Determine what class called a method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an application in mind, but I am not sure how to do this. Say I have some publically accessible method in a DLL file that takes no parameters. Is it possible for this method to know what called it? Can it tell if it were called from a static or instantiated context? From a specific class? What can a method know about how it's being called?

Comment: It can (C# 5.0 made this a lot easier), but it's rather bad design to need to do this outside of possibly some logging frameworks.  Are you sure you *really* need to do this?

Comment: How dynamic does this need to be? An attribute on the method for example could log the calls to the method I believe... Imagine how the Obsolete keyword works.

Comment: I was thinking about the possibility for a class to register itself with another class in a way that could not be spoofed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the method that called the current method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get caller information from a stack trace:

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
MethodBase methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
```

It is possible for this method to know what called it:

```
string typeName = methodBase.DeclaringType.Name;
string methodName = methodBase.Name;
```

It can tell if it were called from a static or instantiated context:

```
bool isStaticCall = methodBase.IsStatic
```

From a specific class:

```
bool isGeneric = methodBase.DeclaringType.IsGenericType;
```

Comment: This method can break if compiled with optimization, because the calling method may be inlined.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do this:

```
var callingClass = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().ReflectedType;
```

The `1` tells the constructor to skip the currently executing method.

Answer (score 2):

If your program has sufficient privileges, it can construct a [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) and examine it frame-by-frame to determine who is the caller. This will get you the calling method, the calling class, and so on.

Comment: What privileges does it take?