# How can I get a reference to the Window that calls a method, and use that to assign the Owner?

Tags: c#

How can I get the calling object inside a called method?

I've had to create a custom MessageBox, which is created as follows:

```
public static class MsgBox
{
    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
    {
        var msg = new CustomMessageBoxWindow(messageBoxText);
        msg.ShowDialog();

        return msg.Result;
    }
}
```

I now need to specify an owner for this MessageBox. I can do this by forcing the developer to pass in the calling object, e.g.

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, Window owner)
```

and set the owner as follows

```
msg.Owner = owner;
```

But this means having to change a lot of calls in a lot of places. It's doable, but it's not ideal. Ideally, I'd be able to find out what class called the MessageBox from inside the Show() method and set it without having to pass any new parameters, e.g.

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
{
    var msg = new CustomMessageBoxWindow(messageBoxText);
    msg.ShowDialog();

    var owner = // somehow get the calling Window;
    msg.Owner = owner;

    return msg.Result;
}
```

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254032/determine-what-class-called-a-method). Perhaps the answers there can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the instance of the caller to your message box.  Reflection will not give you this.  Reflection provides metadata about classes that are in an assembly.  Similarly, StackFrame also gives you metadata (e.g. GetMethod gives you a MethodBase, which gives you characteristics of the method in the stack frame).

I don't know of a way you can get the instance of a calling object without requiring its 'this' pointer as a parameter.  If you derive your message class from 'Form', then you can try the Parent and ParentForm property, but I don't think these are guanteed to be non-Null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing things like this. You will need to use reflection. I unfortunately can't give much details as I'm new to reflection myself, but here's a line of code :

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(2).GetMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();
```

From where I see it, this moves 2 levels up to the stacktrace (in my code I need 2 levels, maybe you'll need more ?). Then the GetMethod returns the calling method, while the DeclaringType property gives you the class in which this method is declared.
I know it won't necessarily solve your problem but maybe this can help...

P.S : I'm doing it in ASP.NET but I don't think this is important as long as the assembly has nothing to do with web...