# How to detect C# Callback handler sender

Tags: c#, .net, callback, handler

I receive some controller from 3rd party API, then i register some event that controller exposes, the event callback handler is with signature:

```
public delegate void SomeCallbackFromAPI(Guid threadId, int someInt)
```

This is not good enough for me, I would like to receive the sender as well because i need to identify this controller from a list of controllers i hold, and the callback does not provide any other valid ID that i can recognize the controller with.

I DO know when this invokes, and if I can the sender I can cast it to my controller type.

Is there a way to get the sender of callback ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When a delegate is invoked it is just as a regular method call, so unless the caller is being passed as a parameter, as in `EventHandler<T>`, you can't grab it.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates contain `Method` and `Target`. You can make the delegate's target contain the info you need, provided you know the controller you're subscribing to when you register your delegate.

```
namespace So17022438CallbackHandlers
{
    delegate void ApiCallback (Guid threadId, int param);

    class Program {
        class Handler {
            public string Name;
            public ApiCallback Callback;

            public Handler (string name)
            {
                Name = name;
                Callback = (id, param) => OnApiCallback(Name, param);
            }
        }

        static void Main (string[] args) {
            var apis = new[] { new Api(), new Api() };
            apis[0].RegisterCallback(new Handler("Name1").Callback);
            apis[1].RegisterCallback(new Handler("Name2").Callback);
            apis[0].CallCallback();
            apis[1].CallCallback();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void OnApiCallback (string name, int param) {
            Console.WriteLine(name + " - " + param);
        }
    }

    class Api {
        private ApiCallback _callback;

        public void RegisterCallback (ApiCallback callback) {
            _callback = callback;
        }

        public void CallCallback () {
            _callback(new Guid(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Actually, no need for classes, it can be done solely with closures. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the caller via the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171974/261050).