# StackFrame.GetMethod().Name

Tags: c#, stack-trace, helpermethods

I'm using this helper to resolve the name of the method that is currently being executed for logging purposes.

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static string GetCurrentMethod()
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);

        return sf.GetMethod().Name;
    }
```

This is the string that is returned `<Frequency>b__46`

"
What does the b__46 mean?
And is there a way to just retrieve the word "Frequency?"

This is calling the helper.

```
    return ProxyCallWrapper.Execute<bool, IBackendJob>((backend, header) =>
    {
        header.CorrelationID = CorrelationID;
        logger.LogInfo(string.Format("### BSL CALL from {0} by {1} : CorrelationID: {2}", this.ToString(), GetCurrentMethod() ,header.CorrelationID));
        return backend.AddJob(header, jobId);
    });
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It sounds like you're calling it from a lambda.

Comment: Can you show the calling code as well?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx http://blog.slaks.net/2012/03/exploring-caller-info-attributes.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is probably being called from a lambda expression. The C# compiler actually converts lambdas to hidden methods inside your class. These methods have special compiler-generated names, like the `<Frequency>b__46` you're seeing. I think you'll find if you look at `GetFrame(2)` you'll see the name you expect. Your function could ignore lambdas by looping up the stack until it finds a valid method name (you can check the method descriptor's [IsSpecialName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for that).

The compiler also generates hidden methods with special names for auto property getters and setters, event add/remove handlers, and some other cases (you won't encounter these since these auto-generated methods can't call your `GetCurrentMethod()`). But note also that manual property getters and setters have "special" names like `get_PropertyName()`, and you may see those if you have a property whose code calls `GetCurrentMethod()`.

Comment: I edited my question to include the code that calls the helper. It is a lambda statement. I will try GetFrame(2) and tell you what I find. A brief explanation of what the numbers inside of GetFrame() would be appreciated.

Comment: @g5insider The argument to `GetFrame()` is just the index of the frame you want. A value of 1 means you're getting the caller's stack frame; 2 means you're getting the caller's caller's frame, and so on, all the way back to `main()` (or the thread / managed entry point).

Comment: @g5insider Because you're passing the lambda to `ProxyCallWrapper.Execute<bool, IBackendJob>()`. This is the nature of lambda expressions; they aren't invoked immediately, they're just objects. Your code's calling `Execute()` which is calling your lambda which is calling `GetCurrentMethod()`.

Comment: Let my try GetFrame(3)

Comment: GetFrame(3) is what I'm looking for. I will have to unit test this but I think it will do.

Comment: GetFrame(3) will only work in the specific scenario in your question. Do you understand that?

Comment: I've just manually added the names instead of using this method of retrieving it from the stack trace. GetFrame(3) as @Biorgbeard stated will only work in some cases and not all. I appreciate the help from everyone. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`<Frequency>b__46` is the name of the method that called `GetCurrentMethod()`.

Since you are calling the method from a lambda, you have to accept that the name of the lambda is beyond your control.

Comment: Surely OP wants the name of the method that called in.. otherwise he could just `return "GetCurrentMethod";`

Comment: Not now that you've deleted the suggestion that he wanted `GetFrame(0)`, no.

Comment: trying GetFrame(0) now

Comment: @g5insider No, don't do that

Comment: GetFrame(0) returns "GetCurrentMethod" the helper method name.

Comment: Indeed it does. Perhaps it would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve.