# How can I tell what object called a method?

Tags: c#

I have a method called CreateNode().  All it does is creates an XElement and returns it.  I have two objects that called this method: Action and ElseAction:

```
var x1 = Action.CreateNode();
var x2 = ElseAction.CreateNode();
```

Both of these objects are of type `Action` and the CreateNode() method resides within the `Action` class.

Within the CreateNode() method, I have a line that creates the root XElement:

```
var xelement = new XElement("actionitem");
```

What I'd like to do is determine whether Action or ElseAction called the CreateNode() method so I can do the following if the caller is ElseAction:

```
var xelement = new XElement("elseactionitem");
```

So, I guess my question is "Can I determine the name of who/what called the CreateNode method?"  Can I do something ilke the following?:

```
if (caller == Action) var xelement = new XElement("actionitem");
if (caller = ElseAction) var xelement = new XElement("elseactionitem");
```

Comment: The Action and ElseAction are differents class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method

Comment: You should override the method in your subclass and implement the class-specific behaviour there. Your base class shouldn't have to have any knowledge about its subclasses or their behaviours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easy to do in .net 4.5

if had a method as follows:

```
public void doAction([CallerMemberName] string fromWhere ="")
{

}
```

if you call doAction the string will be populated from the method who called it.
[callerMemberName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. The best is this:

```
class Action
{
  public virtual XElement CreateNode() {return new XElement("actionitem");}
};

class ElseAction : Action
{
  public override XElement CreateNode() {return new XElement("elseactionitem");}
};
```

Comment: It is only reasonable way, I can imagine code those `else if` statements for `AnotherElseAction` or `NextElseAction` where type system can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here u go: [C# 5.0 Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check on the object (Action or ElseAction), and call the appropriate methods by doing the following:

```
    if (caller is Action) {
        // Logic goes here if the caller is of type 'Action'
        // you can use the item as an 'Action' type like
    (caller as Action).SomeMethodOfAction();
    } else if (caller is ElseAction) {
        // Logic goes here if the caller is of type 'ElseAction'
        (caller as ElseAction).SomeMethodOfElseAction();
    }
```