# CollectionChanged get the instance of object thats holding the collection

Tags: c#, reflection, instance, observablecollection

Is it possbible to get the `Instance` of an item, within the CollectionChanged event?

For Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bars += HelperFoo.Bars_CollectionChanged;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class HelperFoo
{
    public static voic Bars_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //sender is the collection Foo.Bars
        //can I get the Instance of Foo?
    }
}
```

(I wouldnt mind using reflection)

If this isnt possible is there a way to get the Instance of object that intializes an other object?

For Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        var bar = new Bar(); //yes I know, I could write new Bar(this) and provide an overload for this
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        //Get the Foo, since the constructor is called within Foo, is this possible?
        //without providing an overload that takes an object, and just change it to `(new Bar(this))`
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep referring to `FooA`, but your code does not have a `FooA`. I assume you mean `Foo`. Your naming makes this hard to follow. `Foo` and `Bar` would make this a bit more readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the method that called the current method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but that will allow you to identify who called your constructor.

Comment: As @JonB points out your question is very confusing because of your naming. If you are looking for the item being modified/added/removed within the collection you should use NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JonB: thanks for the link, but I would need to get the instance of the object thats calling either related to the collectionchanged or from with a constructor.

Comment: @FodderZone thanks for the link, but I would need the instance of the item thats holding this collection and not the items getting added/removed/replaced/moved/reseted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Gaz but if you are really wanting to do what you describe then add a Dictionary to your HelperFoo class. Then in your Foo class add this as the creator as follows.

```
public static class HelperFoo
{
    private static Dictionary<ObservableCollection<Bar>, object> lookupCreators = new Dictionary<ObservableCollection<Bar>, object>();

    public static void AddBarsCreator(ObservableCollection<Bar> bars, object creator)
    {
        lookupCreators.Add(bars, creator);
    }

    public static void Bars_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Bar> bars = (ObservableCollection<Bar>)sender;
        if (lookupCreators.ContainsKey(bars))
        {

        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
        HelperFoo.AddBarsCreator(Bars, this);
        Bars.CollectionChanged += HelperFoo.Bars_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems rather oddly structured.

If your `HelperFoo` class needs to do something with `Foo`, then pass it `Foo`, and let it subscribe to `Bar` events itself.

If `HelperFoo` shouldn't know anything about `Bars`, then expose an event on `Foo` instead and subscribe to that. You can raise then event inside `Foo` when `Bars` changes.

Have a read up on the [Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: "If your HelperFoo class needs to do something with Foo, then pass it Foo, and let it subscribe to Bar events itself." ... I have like 500 instances of Foo and all need to do a comon thing when the Foo.Bars collection changes, so I believe its memory saver to have a static collection changed event instead of subrcibing it for every instance or Foo, but sadly I need some information about the Foo's instance to handle the logic in collection changed correctly. Would you still suggest registering the collection changed for every instance of Foo?

Comment: Do all 500 Foos contain the same Bar collection? Or are there 500 different collections too? If so I hardly think 500 delegate subscriptions are going to matter much.

Comment: 500 different collections - items between 0 to max 300