# Determine which class or assembly instantiated an object with Castle Windsor container

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I use the newest Castle Windsor container and I would like to create a logger, which will write to file what I want but also write the caller assembly name. So here is an example:

```
namespace Core.Datalayer
{
    public class Foo
    {
       public Foo(ILogger logger)
       {
          logger.Write("test line");
       }
    }
}
```

The container gives the instance correctly, but I cannot figure out how can I determine the Caller assembly name or the Caller class name? I would like that the logger writing to file something like this:

> "assembly Core.Datalayer- test line"

Is there any possibility to determine that where instantiated the ILogger interface?

I tried the Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() but is always Castle.Core because the stack is full with Castle.Core calls.

Comment: Which logging framework are you using?  log4net, nlog, something else?

Comment: I don't use any framework for logging it is just a simple logger. I write the text in file directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the method that called the current method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I have read that post.

Comment: This or similar functionality is built into most major logging frameworks.  I'd really recommend using one!

Comment: I agree using a logging framework is far simpler and better. Still I've tried to answer how to do this with Windsor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subdependency resolver. I think something like the code below should work for you.

```
public class Logger
{
    public Logger(string name)
    {
    }
}

public class LogResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model,
                           DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return dependency.TargetType == typeof(Logger);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model,
                          DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return new Logger(model.Name);
    }
}
```

install the logger int the container with

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new LogResolver());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I struggled with it nearly one day. That's what I want! :)