# How to get Method Name passing as argument to function?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I found a similar question here
[How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)
but answers in this question also give same result as I have mentioned in my first example

Here is method that I am using

```
public class iStore
    {
        public T GetSiteCacheValueByFunc<T>(Func<T> func) where T : class
        {
            var methodName = func.Method.Name;
        }
    }
```

Here I am using `iStore.GetSiteCacheValueByFunc` by using following code I get methodName `<Index>b_2` while I should get `GetAllLanguages`

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var site = BusinessLogic.Caching.iStore;
        var languages = site.GetSiteCacheValueByFunc<IEnumerable<Language>>(() =>  LanguageManager.GetAllLanguages());
    }
```

If I use following code I get correct methodName `GetAllLanguages` but in this way I am not able to pass parameters to GetAllLanguages method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var site = BusinessLogic.Caching.iStore;
    var languages = site.GetSiteCacheValueByFunc<IEnumerable<Language>>(LanguageManager.GetAllLanguages);
}
```

Where I am doing wrong? and how can I get correct methodName?

Comment: In your second example, you're passing in an anonymous function, so a name like `<Index>b_2` is not surprising. But why do you need the method name in the first place?

Comment: I want to filter specific methods

Comment: Code should not change its behavior based on who calls it.

Comment: @MujassirNasir You are solving this the wrong way, I'd recommend you to ask another question on how to best solve your original issue rather this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5 you can use an attribute : [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void MyMethod([CallerMemberName]string myCallerName = null)
{
  //use myCallerName
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if you are handy with this would you please help me how to modify above code with this implementation?

Comment: I don't think this is useful here. `CallerMemberName` causes the compiler to insert the name of the function/property that calls `MyMethod`, not the name of the function that you're passing in. So in Mujassirs last example, you'd get "Index" instead of "GetAllLanguages".