# How to get the object from a MethodBase class instance

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a module [(Fody.MethodTimer](https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer)) that I can extend my classes with attributes. When my class'es method gets executed it, invokes a static method (in another class)

```
public  class CommandBase
{
    [Time]
    public bool test()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public static class MethodTimeLogger
{
    public static void Log(MethodBase methodBase, long milliseconds)
    {
        //Do some logging here
    }
}
```

Basically, after the method is call of test is complete, the Log  method gets executed. As you can see, it get a MethodBase argument and has all that is needed do decribe the method that invoked this method call.

my Question is, If it is possible to get the object that invoked the Log method Call, out of The .NET MethodBase class instance.

Comment: Are you asking how you can get the stacktrace (in your case the calling method) for the current method? Then this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method

Comment: No, I would like to do some update to the object that invoked the Log method. I'll explain more in the edit

Comment: Stack trace will give you the _method_ in which the `Log` function was called, but not the _object_.

Comment: On a static method there is no instance that the method is called on, otherwise you could use the `this`-pointer.

Comment: I want the sender, like in an eventhandler

Comment: How exactly are you calling the method?

Comment: I'm not. The mentioned dll is

Comment: You could always tweak https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer/blob/master/Fody/AsyncMethodProcessor.cs and make your own version that returned more data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  `MethodBase` is extracted from a *type*, not an *instance*.  You will need to pass the instance in as a parameter if you want to invoke methods on it.

Even if you *could*, how would you know what parameter values to use when calling the method?

This is why all built-in event handlers have an `object sender` parameter - so you know which object triggered the event.

Comment: the sender is exactly what I want

Comment: So add a parameter from the sender - why is that not an option?

Comment: Fody is a methodVeawer. The code does not exist until Build time. It get "generated" in build time and out of my control