# Detecting if AuthorizationAttribute manually called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes, authorize-attribute

I have a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` in a legacy MVC5 project:

```
public class AuthorizeWithLoggingAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
     {
         if (!base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)) {Log(FilterContext);}
     }
 }
```

We noticed while looking through the logs, that in addition to being to applied to controllers with `[AuthorizeWithLogging]`, it was being called explicitly elsewhere in the code, generating spurious logs:

```
var filters = new FilterInfo(FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor));
foreach (var authFilter in filters.AuthorizationFilters)
{
    authFilter.OnAuthorization(authContext);
    if (authContext.Result != null) {return false;}
}
```

Is there a way to tell (via `StackTrace` or something) whether the `OnAuthorization` method is being explicitly called, or called from the attribute? The best I currently have is 
`Environment.StackTrace.Contains("at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters")`.

Comment: Why don't you find all references to the `OnAuthorization` method of `AuthorizeAttribute` in your code?

Comment: What MVC version are you using?

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer I did. They're hard to dislodge. If we could do it all over again, we'd do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthorizeAttribute` has a single responsibility: to determine whether or not the user is authorized. This can be used in multiple places in the application for a variety of different reasons.

Any actions that are taken as a result of not being authorized (such as returning a HTTP 401 response) are delegated to a handler of type `ActionResult` that is set to the `AuthorizationContext.Result` property. For example, here is the default implementation of `AuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest`:

```
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // Returns HTTP 401 - see comment in HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs.
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

If you are trying to do auditing when a user is not authorized, you should put the auditing into the `ActionResult` handler, not in the custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. This ensures the auditing is only executed if the `ActionResult` is executed (that is, when the current page is not authorized), not in every case authorization is checked.

```
public class AuthorizeWithLoggingAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new LoggingActionResult(new HttpUnauthorizedResult(), filterContext);
    }
}

public class LoggingActionResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly ActionResult innerActionResult;
    private readonly AuthorizationContext filterContext;

    public LoggingActionResult(ActionResult innerActionResult, AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (innerActionResult == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("innerActionResult");
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        this.innerActionResult = innerActionResult;
        this.filterContext = filterContext;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // Do logging (or apparently you want auditing) here
        Log(this.filterContext);

        innerActionResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

> NOTE: I would name them `AuthorizeWithAuditingAttribute` and `AuditingActionResult` since you clearly want auditing, not logging in this case.

Answer (score 1):

One route you could go with would be use [StackFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx). This would be a little cleaner than what you have currently. More details can be found here: 
[How can I find the method that called the current method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method/171974#171974)