# Get Calling Class with System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(): Why does the unit test fail? c#

Tags: c#, system.reflection, system.diagnostics

I have the following function that should output the class name of the calling class. Handily I have tested it and it works, it returns the calling class name.

```
public static string ExtractCallingClassName() {
  using System.Diagnostics;
  // Get call stack
  StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(); 
  // Get calling method name
  return stackTrace.GetFrame(2).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
}
```

However, the unit test returns `RuntimeMethodHandle` instead of the test class name.

```
[Fact]
public void ExtractCallingClassNameShouldExtractCorrect() {
      string expectedName = this.GetType().Name;
      string actualName = AssemblyExtractor.ExtractCallingClassName();
      Assert.Equal(expectedName, actualName);
}
```

Output:

```
Assert.Equal() Failure
          ↓ (pos 0)
Expected: AssemblyExtractorTest
Actual:   RuntimeMethodHandle
          ↑ (pos 0)
```

The test is in another project. The source project is linked in the test project as project reference.

Does anyone know why the test fails?

The source project is a class library.
Will it work if I include it as package reference?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method

Comment: I also think you might reinventing the wheel. See CallerMemberName ....