# Audit.Net Get the name of the method which called .SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, audit.net

I have the following Setup

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup() // Triggered on a database save.
    .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
        .AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
            .Map<Item, AuditLog>()
            .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
            {
                auditEntity.AuditData = entry.ToJson();
                auditEntity.AuditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                auditEntity.CallingMethod = "Calling Method"; <-- Where I need the calling method.
            })
        )
    );
```

```
    public async Task DoSomeWork() {  //<--- I want to get "DoSomeWork"
        // Some work..
        await dbConn.SaveChangesAsync();
        return updated;
    }
```

How can I get access to the method which called .saveChangesAsync so I know where it was triggered from? I've checked using `StackTrace` however that is flooded with library level frames which are not very helpful and I can't find the correct parent method.

I see in `evt` there is a that it provides a calling parent name, however that is just one level up so is just the "SaveChangesAsync" method.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv No I mentioned I used the stack trace (sorry called it stack frame). Will update that now.

Comment: Using `CallerMemberName` is a better idea. Walking the call stack is very expensive. That's not auditing anyway, that's application-level tracing.

Comment: That's what I'd like to use, but I don't know how I'm meant to apply it to the Audit.Core.Confirguration?

Comment: Even for tracing, it's a better idea to use the [built-in classes ActivitySource and Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs). ASP.NET Core itself uses Activity for actions, which means you can already trace action calls. There's additional instrumentation for EF Core that only needs registering a package and a trace target, eg a file or a tracing server like Jaeger or Zipkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the code that calls `SaveChangesAsync` and you are inheriting your DbContext from AuditDbContext ([High-Level SaveChanges interception](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#high-level-savechanges-interception)), then you could add a new SaveChanges method with an optional parameter decorated with `[CallerMemberName]` and store the caller member name in a custom field of the AuditEvent.

For example:

```cs
public class YourDbContext : AuditDbContext
{
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException("Should call SaveChangesAuditAsync");

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAuditAsync([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        this.AddAuditCustomField("Caller", memberName);
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

So, in your AuditEntityAction you can get the caller member name from the custom field:

```cs
    ...
    .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
    {
        auditEntity.CallingMethod = evt.CustomFields["Caller"];
    })
```

Now your `DoSomeWork()` must call the new method:

```cs
public async Task DoSomeWork() 
{
    ...
    await dbConn.SaveChangesAuditAsync();
    return updated;
}
```