# c# Set a variable into a referred DLL from caller assembly

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

I have a DLL shared into 2 projects (into the same solution), this DLL is a library of functions used from the other 2 projects, first one is a Windows Service (exe file) and the second one is a WebService  (DLL file)

Now, to be much specific, a function need to know who is the caller to customize a path

There is a way to set a variable into the callers projects thats instruct the called DLL?

I tryed to use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName but it works different if it called from a EXE and a DLL and anyway doesn't looks a clean way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make the path configurable and add a proper configuration fitting to either project?

Comment: you can request the stack frame of the caller and extract what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method

Comment: Why do not introduce static variable `MyDllClass.SomeSwitch` inside DLL project. Then set this variable by executing code.

Comment: @Ralf paths are different into 2 projects, I can't use one for both, is the opposite

Comment: @yacc not exactly, I try now but it return to me the function calling, not the assembly calling

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you explain better? Do you have an example or related article?

Comment: Inside DLL: `public static class DLLVariables { public static bool InsideSerice; }`, In Windows Service - set once `DLLVariables.InsideSerice = true`. Then you will know who is executing code.

Comment: What's the problem with either adding a path parameter to the function if it's just one (or a few), or else adding a separate method for setting the path explicitly?

Comment: Still that's a case for a config file. One dll with two different config files. Or rather one per project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with a "trick" :) and I have to thank @yacc to let me the correct path...

```
public static string GetCallingMethod()
    {
         string retval = "";

         StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
         StackFrame[] frames = st.GetFrames();
         foreach (StackFrame sFrame in frames)
         {
            if (sFrame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName.StartsWith("MyAssembly"))
            {
                retval = sFrame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;
            }
         }

         return retval;
    }
```

*retval* will contain le full name of the assembly caller, in my projects both names starts with "MyAssembly"

Thanks all for help