# In C#, is it possible to know if the method is being executed in async flow?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Can we have a method `IsInAsyncContext` that identifies if the control is inside an async execution flow or not? Check the following usage.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    IsInAsyncContext(); // Should return false.
    AsyncMethod().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    SyncMethod();
}

private static async Task AsyncMethod()
{
    IsInAsyncContext(); // Should return true.
    SyncMethod();
}

private static void SyncMethod()
{
    // Should return false if called from Main, true if called from AsyncMethod.
    IsInAsyncContext();
}
```

Optional Read: To give some context, I am using `AsyncLocal<T>` to be able to get/set different instance of `T` in every invocation of some async method, say `AsyncMethod`. But if I happen to set this object inside `Main`, then the way how `AsyncLocal` works, every invocation of `AsyncMethod` gets the same instance. Sharing the same object causes race conditions if multiple invocations of `AsyncMethod` are running in parallel. The solution, I can think of, is to set/get a separate object if it's root non-async context and use `AsyncLocal<T>.Value` for async contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: @Markus While I have seen a proposed solution that involves `[CallerMemberName]`, I don't think that's a suitable question to mark this one a duplicate of.

Comment: As the title suggests, it's a general question on whether one can know if the method is being executed in the async context. The solution should not depend on specific method name or pattern. Also, it is not necessary that it's just the immediate caller method that is async. It can be that the async method exists several levels down the call stack, but still `IsInAsyncContext` should be able to return true.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute) which uses `AsyncStateMachineAttribute` as an indication of `async` method. For nested methods one might probably check the entire call stack.

Comment: There is nothing async about that "async" method. I would guess it will be executed sync...

Comment: Maybe it is enough for you to set flag via [AsyncLocal<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-8.0) and check later?

Comment: If you insert a `await Task.Yield().ConfigureAwait(false);` inside your async method, you should have ensured you're no longer on the original context. So do that before working with the `AsyncLocal` and you shouldn't have to interrogate your callers.

Comment: _"Sharing the same object causes race conditions if multiple invocations of AsyncMethod are running in parallel."_ - can you please elaborate? Possibly this problem can be solved insted?

Comment: @GuruStron, the problem should be solvable by adding locks, but so far we have been relying on `AsyncLocal` to ensure there is a different object to each async invocation, and accessing the object in outer method invalidated that assumption. There are different pieces of code that we can edit or just use, so it would be difficult to trim down the requirements in this forum. Though, I really appreciate the helpful comments and answers on this page.

Answer (score 5):

The execution of async methods is not much different from regular methods. If your requirement is not so strict, you can check on the stack to see if the method is run inside `IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext`.

```
public static bool IsInAsyncContext()
{
    var st = new StackTrace();
    for(int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; ++i)
    {
      if(st.GetFrame(i)?.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.
         GetInterface("System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine") != null)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need to cover whether the method is running by `Task.Run/Task.Factory.StartNew...`, you can check with `Task.CurrentId != null`.

Comment: I had similar idea, but you have beaten me to it) Few notes I would argue should be added to the answer: 1) this can be not very good performance-wise 2) Not sure that this will support [custom async state machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/async-method-builders), though it should be far more rare problem then the first one (also possibly it can be used to determine that you are in async method =).

Comment: Yes, this is slow. I have checked your link and it seems that this new feature will only affect which builder the state machine uses to run, async code will still be generated in the MoveNext method, so this is supported.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to analyzing the stack trace (which 1. can be relatively slow 2. in theory can be brittle since it relies on implementation details, though it is unlikely to change in the near future) you can consider using some marker `AsyncLocal`, though you will need to manually set it at the start of every async call:

```
public class Helper
{
    private static AsyncLocal<bool> Marker = new();
    public static void Mark() => Marker.Value = true;
    public static bool IsInAsyncContext() => Marker.Value;
}
```

```cs
static async Task AsyncMethod()
{
    Helper.Mark();
    // the rest of the method ...
}
```

Though obviously this will require some manual work (which currently can't be automated without 3rd party libraries or preview features, but if you are up for them - you can look into [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or [C# 12 preview feature - interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#interceptors)). Also possibly something can be done with [custom async method builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/async-method-builders), though not sure it is worth the hustle to go down that route.