Is there a good way to figure out what called a public async Task in C#
I'm debugging a C# ASP.NET website in
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.0

I have a breakpoint at the top of a public async Task and this particular task has many references.
Is there an better way to figure out what's called it than putting breakpoints in all of the task's references?
When I hit the breakpoint in my public async Task Visual Studio says that I'm at the top of the callstack.

What type of method have you put the bp on - is it a top level REST controller endpoint for example ?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method
