# Can you automatically pass "this" as parameter?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

Is there an option to automatically pass `this` as parameter to a function? For example, you can use `[CallerMemberName]` to automatically pass `string` name. I'm looking for exact option with `this`.

Example:

```
void PassMeThis([AutomaticThisParam] object source);
```

and usage:

```
public class SomeClass{    
    void SomeMethod(){
        PassMeThis(); // instead of PassMeThis(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: `PassMeThis()` and `PassMeThis(this)` would be two separate methods, though

Comment: Where is located the PassMeThis method? If it is inside the same class then what is the purpose of this thing?

Comment: Most likely you are looking for .NET Extension methods, as @Willie answered. Alternatively, if you want default context data that is automatically picked up by such functions in your code in a given execution context, like a thread, then there are alternatives to that as well - like ThreadStatic fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes absolutely. This is called an extension Method.

1. Create a static class 
   `Public static class MethodExtensions`
2. Add a static method to it like this
   `public static PassMeThis(this SomeClass model) { // }`
3. Call the method like this (referring to your code example):
   `this.PassMeThis()`

And it's automaticly filled.
I hope thats what you were looking for

Comment: I think you need the Extension attribute as well (but maybe C# does this automatically for you unlike VB.NET)

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams in VB you will need it. In C# it's automaticly clear by using the `this` keyword in the param signature

Comment: Oh! How did I not think of this? Thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

If `PassMeThis` is **in the same class** (or ancestor), as in your example, there is no point, this is avaiable there, too.

If it is **in another class**, there is **no** way to automatically get a reference to the calling object: [IS there any way to get a reference to the calling object in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420541/10614791)