# C# static method inlining

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Is it posible that the JIT compiler will make a static method inlined?

For exmaple, we have some code:

```
class A
{
     public static int c(int v)
     {
          return v*2
     }
}
..............
Console.WriteLine(A.c(2));
```

In wihich circumstances can method `public static int c(int v)` be inlined by the JIT compiler?

Comment: According to [Can I check if the C# compiler inlined a method call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616779/can-i-check-if-the-c-sharp-compiler-inlined-a-method-call) the C# compiler isn't responsible for this, but the JIT compiler takes care of this.

Comment: What do you mean by inlining in C#?

Comment: @Alek Depler I mean that JIT will place IL(byte code) of method right to the place of call.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the compiler (C# or JIT) may or may not inline for performance at its own discretion, but you can always guarantee that the language will behave as designed. i.e. the side effects of the method, if any (none in this case), will happen before the call to writeline.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx) your answer is Yes.