# Performance cost of Method Encapsulation

Tags: c#

Is there a performance cost to encapsulating methods? A very brief, arbitrary example:

```
        public static decimal Floor(decimal value)
        {
            return Math.Floor(value);
        }
```

Would the above function be inlined? And if so, would it be the exact same as calling Math.Floor() from the code? I did Google before writing this.

Comment: Why would you to this ?

Comment: @KevinAvignon Writing a MathHelper class, with your own functions and the .NET ones, too. Basically a one-stop-shop.

Comment: ***If*** there is a performance overhead should you really be concerned ? Another way to put it ; do you currently have a performance bottleneck which has been profiled and the origin is this exact kind of method ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht Nope. I was just being curious; no harm in asking, right?

Comment: @Krythic: Yes, absolutely no harm in asking. And people should point you in the right direction. :)

Comment: @displayName but people did not... Right direction: read [horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert. Then read something about inlining in C# (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616779/can-i-check-if-the-c-sharp-compiler-inlined-a-method-call). Than measure and update your question if you still have one (or self-answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: With all due respect to Eric Lippert, I didn't even bring him into the discussion here. It is not about what anyone said. I have read his 'horses' article. IMO, he wrote it to discourage people from performing micro-optimizations and wasn't meaning to avert people from knowing the cost of a method call.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: In fact, the best way to avoid people from performing micro-optimizations is to inform them about the throw-away cost of it.

Comment: @KevinAvignon Here is also an example where someone did what I was talking about(look to the bottom of the page) http://svn.soapboxcore.com/svn/trunk/Physics2D/AdvanceMath/MathHelper.cs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method likely will be inlined (at JIT time, C# compiler *does not* inline method in IL). Even if not cost is unlikely to impact your overall program. Since optimization and performance numbers are specific to particular code/application you need to measure your case if you see performance problem.

In particular [Writing Faster Managed Code: Know What Things Cost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) article  on MSDN gives following estimate for cost of method call: *max 6.8 nano-seconds* (for 2003 level machine) if the call is not optimized.

Consider reading the rest of the article. In particular Table 3 talks about not only the cost of method calls, but also how much do the operations *as trivial as addition, subtraction, multiplication and division cost.*

If you need to confirm whether method is inlined - it is covered in many SO questions like [Can I check if the C# compiler inlined a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616779/can-i-check-if-the-c-sharp-compiler-inlined-a-method-call)

Comment: "still if you want to know such a trivial thing, you should be informed." and "First make a working software then do optimizations instead of doing premature optimizations. but I sincerely feel that's a bad answer." Upvote for both.

Comment: displayName, you should consider providing something that is close to an answer... (And maybe remove meta comments about other possible answers).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Updated my answer. Requesting a great guy's up-vote if he is happy now. :D

Comment: @displayName I've "slightly" edited your post to show what I think would answer the question by rewording information you've provided. My main concern was 6.8ns looked like just taken from thin air... Feel free to roll back.