# Get the name of the current method

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

This is kind of a silly question, but is it possible to get the name of the method that is currently being executed from within that method?

```
Public Sub SomeMethod()

   Dim methodName as String = System.Reflection.[function to get the current method name here?]

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/06/29/83654.aspx

Comment: That's actually how to get the name of the calling method, not the currently executing method. Still cool, though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

[`System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx)

Comment: better use the base class: 
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();

Comment: @marstone - Could you explain why please?

Comment: @PunkyGuy someone said: “Although both calls have exactly the same effect, it's in general a bad idea to invoke Shared functions on subclasses of the class on which they are actually defined”. reference:http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/457334-methodinfo-methodbase

Comment: This does not always work in optimized situations. Sometimes the current method is optimized away.

Answer (score 48):

The other methods are close to what was asked, but they don't return the *string* value. But this does:

```
Dim methodName$ = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

Answer (score 7):

To guarantee that any of the answers presented to this question actually work (`System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name`) at runtime, you need to add an attribute. There are no compiler/runtime flags that I know of that break this method:

the function you are trying to get the name of [must be marked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5169272/57883)

- F# `[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)>]`
- VB: `<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)>`
- C#: `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`

Also, nowadays, there is the [`nameof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator in VB, C#([and maybe F# soon](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1003-nameof-operator.md))
which for your case would be `nameof(SomeMethod)` (I believe the syntax would be the same for VB and C# here)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be to use [Caller​Member​Name​Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.7) from the System.​Runtime.​Compiler​Services namespace to populate an optional parameter.  For example ...

```
Private Function GetMethodName(<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName>
    Optional memberName As String = Nothing) As String

    Return memberName

End Function
```

The function would be invoked as you would expect...

```
Public Sub DoSomeWork()
    Dim methodName As String = GetMethodName()
    Console.WriteLine($"Entered {methodName}")

    ' Do some work
End Sub
```

Rather than 'just' retrieving the method name, the function might also make use of the method name retrieved to further simplify code.  For example...

```
Private Sub TraceEnter(
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName>
    Optional memberName As String = Nothing)

    Console.WriteLine($"Entered {memberName}")

End Sub
```

... which might be used like this ...

```
Public Sub DoSomeWork()
    TraceEnter()

    ' Do some work

End Sub
```

Other attributes in the CompilerServices namespace may be used in similar fashion to retrieve the full path (at compile time) of the source file and/or the line number of the call.  See the CallerMemberNameAttribute documentation for sample code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim methodName As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```