# Retrieve Assembly currently which use another Assembly

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-assembly

I'm trying to get the assembly of a "currently using by" assembly and I can't figure out how I can do this. I were able to do it when it is referenced in a *Form App*, but it's is not working when used in a *Web Service*.

To get it from a WinForm, I used : `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` which return my CallingApp's dll well and then have access to his Assembly. But when it is use for a Web Service, it return the Current DLL itself instead of Web Service's one.

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

**Edit #1**

More precisely : *MyWebService* reference *MyDLL*. In *MyDLL*, I want to get the *MyWebService* or any other Project Assemblies which use *MyDLL*. That why I use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` which work perfectly for a Win Form app... but not with a Web Service.

Comment: How could a web service know what assembly called it? It's stateless. It's a web service.

Comment: Hope you guys will understand what I mean here... I must tell that I usualy talking french so it's sometimes difficult for me to explain what I mean precisely...

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: It is in fact, the DLL, referenced IN a webservice who want to know the Assembly of the Webservice.

Comment: `GetCallingAssembly` is simply looking at next line on call stack. You can do it too in debugger and likely you'll see the reason of behavior you see.

Comment: In fact, I don't know if my approach is good... In other words, I just want to know, who's using my Class Library's in order to Logs theses informations somewhere and monitoring it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine two different approaches:

- [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Via StackTrace you may have to iterate through each frame in order to determine the assembly.

This thread may give you some hints:

[C# - Get calling method's Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478814/c-sharp-get-calling-methods-assembly)

Comment: Is it the best way to do it? I mean, in fact, it is based on an example I saw somewhere... But is there anyway other way I should consider to do what I want? I mean, a class library should know from where it is call and what called it? In other word, I just want to know, who's using my Class Library's in order to Logs theses informations somewhere and monitoring it.

Comment: Your question is quite valid, and I asked myself the same thing before. But some characteristics of how C# handles its stack - JIT inline calls, for example - may render both approaches unreliable. To my limited knowledge, tracing the stack back -usually- yields the most reliable information.