# Why would the same DateTime value yield different displayed time for different users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization, timezone

In my ASP.NET application I use code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600990) to find the build date of the application as UTC. The UTC value read from the assembly file is then formatted as follows:

```
//DateTime time    
return time.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Now one user opens the page served by that application and sees

```
28 сен 2012 04:13:56
```

and notifies the other user who opens the same page and sees

```
27 Sep 2012 12:14:32
```

Both requests are served by the same application deployed to clean Windows Azure VMs from the very same package, so it's surely exactly the same code being run for both users.

Clearly strings are formatted differently because of different localization for requests from different users. One user sees month displayed as `Sep` and the other sees it as `сен` (equivalent of `Sep` in Russian).

Why do the hours differ? Are they also adjusted according to some timezone that depends on localization?

Comment: Well, yes they are : the day and hours are different : obviously, when it is 4am in Russia on Sep 28th, it is 12 on sep 27th somewhere else(certainly in western part of earth)... but what is weird is that minutes / sec should not change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious explanation is that the `DateTime` values are, in fact, different.

The code you linked uses `GetCallingAssembly`, and you should note that [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) that:

> If the method that calls the GetCallingAssembly method is expanded inline by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler, or if its caller is expanded inline, the assembly that is returned by GetCallingAssembly may differ unexpectedly

To debug this, I would start by displaying `time.Ticks` and `time.Kind`: if these are identical, you know it's a display problem.  If they're different, you need to look at how you're generating the time value.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The code calling the function that reads the timestamp was inside .aspx which is precompiled on actual deployment. So depending on whether the call is inlined it will either be time of build or time of ASP.NET precompilation.

Comment: Here's how to disable inlining of a specific function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5169272/57428