# How to ensure that a method can only be called from a specific dll

Tags: .net, security, design-patterns, code-security

I need to prepare my database for unit testing and hence in the set up method I want to get rid of the data.

However, I don't want to be anybody else but the unit test dll to be able to call into my `DeleteAllData()` method in my Data Access Layer. What can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While others already suggested how to restrict code making calls to your method, they do not create a security boundary and can be spoofed (unless you sign both assemblies and verify the evidence).

Having a method in your business logic called DeleteAllData sounds pretty scary to me. If this method is only used from a unit test, I would probably move it to the unit test assembly. If that is not possible, I would at least put the code in a [compiler directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to only compile in debug mode.

Comment: nice, i will certainly do!

Comment: "they do not create a security boundary and can be spoofed (unless you sign both assemblies and verify the evidence)." > that's why using `InternalsVisibleTo` needs a signed assembly name to work. So it *is* validated and can't be spoofed that easy. You need a breach in the certificate authority to break this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman InternalsVisibleTo works just fine with delay signed assemblies which are not really signed.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign both your assemblies, and then use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to make the unit test assembly the only one able to see the `internal`s. You need to make all methods, properties and classes `internal` that you only want to expose to the unit test project.

MSDN on the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`:

> Specifies that types that are ordinarily visible only within the current assembly are visible to a specified assembly.

Comment: @dexter: Misread your question initially. Patrick's answer is correct when you need to reference internals in one assembly from another, such as a unit test assembly. I left my answer because he implies using `internal`, but doesn't say so explicitly.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I want to believe there is gotta be another way to do this except for relying on the .net framework to do the checks using the attribute. Some kinda factory pattern with modifications for checking the caller in the callee? But maybe what you are proposing is the best way I am just contemplating.

Comment: Why not relying on the framework? Do you think you can do better? I have no idea how to do it different...

Comment: @dexter: You can always hack in the IL and get the method out. No way to prevent that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, how about this type of hack: make the method private and use reflection in the test assembly to invoke it.

Comment: That is still the same... The documented way is better. Let .Net check the evidence.

Answer (score 1):

you could probably use a combination of [Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) and [interrogation of the call stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `DeleteAllData()` method to ensure that your method is only being called by the method you expect.

You might need to [prevent the jitter inlining your method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169219/preventing-jit-inlining-on-a-method) to ensure that the calling assembly method and call stack are preserved when they get to your `DeleteAllData()` method.

The call stack might be enough, but the calling assembly might also be needed.

I've not tried this but think it should work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Mark it with the `internal` keyword. From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx):

> The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

Comment: @Chris Pratt - this would have worked if my code just belonged to one assembly. However, my Data Access code with contenxt.Delete<T> is in its own assembly, versus the client for the call in question is in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more approach to achieve thing mentioned in the question.

If you are using VSTS unit test.

Make the method as private in class so that other classes and assemblies can not access that.

Now to invoke that private method from Unit test use PrivateObject

Here is Microsoft documentation of the PrivateObject :- [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx)

How to use Private Object :- [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632100/Testing-private-methods-functions-using-VSTS-unit)