# Why is copying a structure not slower than changing its data within a method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very simple C# `ref` structure representing a three-dimensional point:

```cs
public ref struct Point
{
    public double X, Y, Z;

    // add in place
    public void Add(Point other)
    {
        X += other.X;
        Y += other.Y;
        Z += other.Z;
    }
    
    // add operator
    public static Point operator +(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return new Point { X = a.X + b.X, Y = a.Y + b.Y, Z = a.Z + b.Z };
    }
}
```

The structure has two ways of letting you add two points together: the first is by using `Add(Point)` , to add another point in place, the second is by using the `+` operator, equivalent to a static method accepting two `Point`s and returning the sum.

I expected the `AddPoint` method to be either faster than `+` or equally fast in virtually every case, for two reasons: firstly, it accepts a single point as argument, thus requires only one copy; secondly, it does not require creating a new point.

To test this, I created two methods to benchmark. They both compute the sum of a series of coordinates using the `Point` structure, and the only difference between the two is the line summing the points. In this first method, the sum is computed via `Point.Add(Point)` :

```cs
public Point AddInPlace()
{
    Point result = new Point();

    foreach ((double, double, double) coordinate in _coordinates)
    {
        Point point = new Point
        {
            X = coordinate.Item1, 
            Y = coordinate.Item2, 
            Z = coordinate.Item3
        };

        result.Add(point); // add in place 
    }

    return result;
}
```

In this second method, the sum is computed via the `+` operator:

```cs
public Point AddOperator()
{
    Point result = new Point();

    foreach ((double, double, double) coordinate in _coordinates)
    {
        Point point = new Point
        {
            X = coordinate.Item1, 
            Y = coordinate.Item2, 
            Z = coordinate.Item3
        };

        result = point + result; // add with + operator 
    }

    return result;
}
```

It turns out that the `Add` method is not faster, and it is (on average) slower. I am reporting here some of the results (I have only included NET6 for brevity, but the numbers are similar on other framework versions). `N` is the number of elements in the coordinates array.

| Method | Job | Runtime | N | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **AddInPlace** | **.NET 6.0** | **.NET 6.0** | **100** | **91.00 ns** | **0.575 ns** | **0.537 ns** |
| AddOperator | .NET 6.0 | .NET 6.0 | 100 | 89.92 ns | 0.633 ns | 0.592 ns |
| **AddInPlace** | **.NET 6.0** | **.NET 6.0** | **1000** | **927.93 ns** | **4.706 ns** | **4.172 ns** |
| AddOperator | .NET 6.0 | .NET 6.0 | 1000 | 926.57 ns | 2.606 ns | 2.310 ns |
| **AddInPlace** | **.NET 6.0** | **.NET 6.0** | **10000** | **9,379.43 ns** | **106.127 ns** | **94.079 ns** |
| AddOperator | .NET 6.0 | .NET 6.0 | 10000 | 9,303.92 ns | 18.739 ns | 16.611 ns |
| Benchmarked with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.html): |  |  |  |  |  |  |

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.12, Windows 11
Intel Xeon W-2235 CPU 3.80GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
```

I tried reading the IL code generated for the two methods but I did not get to any conclusion.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As far as I can see the difference is small and usually less than the `Error`, so I would say that the "faster" conclusion is a bit far-fetched.

Comment: Yeah, the assembly is almost identical, and your differences are very small. I don't think there's much to conclude here.

Comment: As for why - the difference basically is the write location (since those are structs and there is no allocations going on). _"it does not require creating a new point."_ - I have not checked the IL/ASM but I would expect the "point creation" in this case is just one time allocation of memory on stack.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgZgAQWAJwK4GNhIAoD2AlgHbACwAUAN5VL1KJIAmBGARgDYCmSAGgBokATSEAtANxU6DAPSykYZsySkkAB05gs3GfSZwALEgCCygBSFSuAsAAW3NAEo9SWpQaf+SANQBeJFsHNAA6PikPL3phXwCgxxDhCKj6MVjA+wTJVwBfV1d5RWVA9UcwYAI0VwMARgA2fGIyErKKtF9LJtwwIStm9hdI+ncUxgB2JBJuAHdG6zdvALAw3yR2MKEYpcTV9dEkNO20nzWQtJzkhjzKHKA===. The only difference is instruction ordering and very slight changes to memory access.

Comment: @GuruStron I wrote '**not** faster, and it is (on average) slower'. The '(on average) slower' part is motivated by the fact that the average time was smaller in almost all cases, which might be a coincidence but might also be an indication that the operator is a tiny bit faster.

Comment: @LorenzoCelli I've used conclusion from the title.

Comment: I don't think you can draw that conclusion. BDN has done some quite precise statistics on the error margins, and you can't really hand-wave those down based on gut feeling. If you look at the assembly in my previous comment, you can see that the two implementations are practically identical. If there are real differences in time, those will be explained by things like CPU internals, memory/cache access patterns, etc -- the sort of stuff that's pretty hard to explore unless you have deep knowledge in that area. That's well outside the realms of .NET/C#.

Comment: Regarding the other comments, they do not seem to explain why the operator method is not slower considering that it has two arguments, thus two values to copy. How can the two methods be equally fast?

Comment: Will change the title then

Comment: @LorenzoCelli Because the optimizing JIT figured out that they were doing effectively the same thing, and managed to optimize both down to the same code, near enough. In one case the target is the current instance (which is passed into the method as a hidden `this` pointer), whereas in the other case the target is something that the caller allocated (which is again probably passed into the method, as the result is too large to fit in a single register). Again see the link in my prior comment.

Comment: The JIT also seems to have recognised that neither method mutates its parameters (those methods only access fields: there are no method calls, non-inlined property accesses, etc), and so there is no need to add a defensive copy of those parameters.

Comment: Reading the assembly properly (x86 isn't my strong suit), `Point.Add(Point)` takes a pointer to the `this` instance in `ecx`, and the `other` parameter on the stack (see `esp`), and writes back to the `this` instance. `Point.op_Addition(Point, Point)` takes both `a` and `b` on the stack (both accessed via `esp`) and writes the result to memory which the caller allocated, which is pointed to by `ecx`. Both of those operations are pretty much identical: "Load a.X, load b.X, add them, store into result.X". It's just that in the first case, "a" and "result" happen to be the same.

Comment: @canton7 I'm not sure about your explanation. I think the only reason the two methods I benchmarked (`AddOperator` and `AddInPlace`) are equally fast is that the compiler managed to inline the addition in both cases. But if you [prevent inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169219/preventing-jit-inlining-on-a-method) then the difference in performance becomes clear and `AddOperator` takes almost double the time than `AddInPlace`, proving there is a significant difference in invoking one or the other, even if the compiled asm code for the two is still very similar.

Comment: @LorenzoCelli The time taken is probably in the caller though, not in `AddOperator` itself? As you can very clearly see for yourself in the link I provided, the bodies of the two implementations are pretty much identical.