# Get the name of the currently executing method in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to get the name of the currently executing method in a dotnet core application.

There are lots of examples of how to do this with regular c# eg

- [Get the name of the current method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051217/get-the-name-of-the-current-method)
- [How to get the name of the current method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code)

However the apis for both methods appear not to be there in core yet (see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1420)

Is there another way I can get the executing method name in .net core?

Comment: Why not just use `nameof(YourCurrentMethod)`?

Comment: Also,  a more relevent GitHub issue would be https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12496

Comment: `nameof(YourCurrentMethod)` isn't much better than just using a string, thanks for the issue link looks like that method is also due in a future release. Maybe the answer is just not possible atm

Comment: No, its a lot better than using a string. If you rename the function the `nameof(YourCurrentMethod)` gets updated too if you use the rename tools (and a compiler error to remind you to fix it if you don't)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[**CallerMemberNameAttribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method.

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output:
//  message: Something happened.
//  member name: DoProcessing
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs
//  source line number: 31
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to use :

**System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name**

Comment: Used to work - but does not work in asp.net core :(

Comment: It does not, but this does: System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name . I should note it does not return the exact method name, but it's pretty close and for my needs, sufficiently unique. For example, I have a method called GetMembersAsync() it will return a value of "<GETMEMBERSASYNC>D__18".

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Core  3.1, to get the current method name, use:

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

Comment: Doesn't work in an async method, returns "MoveNext".

Answer (score 1):

Tested in NetCore 6, works for Async and sync methods:

```cs
var FullName = methodBase.ReflectedType.FullName;
string LoggedMethodName;

if (FullName.Contains("async", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    LoggedMethodName = FullName.Replace("+<", ".").Substring(0, FullName.IndexOf(">") - 1);
}
else
{
    LoggedMethodName = FullName + "." + methodBase.Name;
}
```

So if I have a `Class` in a given `Namespace1` exposing `MethodX`, I'll get:

```cs
"Namespace1.Class.MethodX"
```