# How to find the FULL name of the calling method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I find the full name of a calling method in C#? I have seen solutions:

*[How I can get the calling methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394850/how-i-can-get-the-calling-methods-in-c-sharp)*

*[How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)*

*[Get Calling function name from Called function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310145/get-calling-function-name-from-called-function-in-c-sharp)*

But they only give me the top level. Consider the example:

```
namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test();
        }

        static void test()
        {
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
            Console.WriteLine(methodBase.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This simply outputs 'Main'. How can I get it to print 'Sandbox.Program.Main'?

It's for a simple logging framework that I am working on.

---

Adding onto Matzi's Answer:

Here is the solution:

```
namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test();
        }

        static void test()
        {
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
            var Class = methodBase.ReflectedType;
            var Namespace = Class.Namespace;         // Added finding the namespace
            Console.WriteLine(Namespace + "." + Class.Name + "." + methodBase.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

It produces 'Sandbox.Program.Main' like it should.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using System.Reflection to Get a Method's Full Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968352/using-system-reflection-to-get-a-methods-full-name)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968352/using-system-reflection-to-get-a-methods-full-name).

```
MethodBase method = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
string methodName = method.Name;
string className = method.ReflectedType.Name;

Console.WriteLine(className + "." + methodName);
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question just to add on how I figured out to find the Namespace.

Comment: Does not work. The method may not be the calling method but one of the ones outside - the calling method may not exist anymore, i.e. have been inlined.

Comment: Is it possible to get nested classes also? If I made a class inside of Program, lets call it `Foo`, And I have a method in `Foo` (lets call it `Bar`) call `Program.test()` It should print `Sandbox.Program.Foo.Bar`

Comment: @TomTom, I don't really know (as in could be very wrong!), but if it has been inlined then, in MSIL, it doesn't exist as a 'method'. I don't know how a runtime method will be able to get something that only exists before compilation.

Comment: @Matzi - That made my life so easy. Perfect answer!

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to get the full name is:

```
 this.GetType().FullName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Or try this:

```
string method = string.Format("{0}.{1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

And if you want to display the most recent function call, you can use:

```
StackTrace st  = new StackTrace();
StackFrame sf  = st.GetFrame(0);
var methodName = sf.GetMethod();
```

But if you want to display the tree of calling functions, you can do it like this:

```
if (st.FrameCount >1)
{
     // Display the highest-level function call
     // in the trace.
     StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount-1);
     Console.WriteLine("  Original function call at top of call stack):");
     Console.WriteLine("      {0}", sf.GetMethod());
}
```

For more [information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That returns the name of the current method not the calling method as the OP wants

Comment: yes, you are right, if you want to display the most recent function call, you can use:
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); st.GetFrame(0);
, but if you want to display the tree of calling functions, you can do it like this:
if (st.FrameCount >1)
{
  // Display the highest-level function call 
  // in the trace.
  StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount-1);
  Console.WriteLine("  Original function call at top of call stack):");
  Console.WriteLine("      {0}", sf.GetMethod());
}
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

With this method you can reliably get the full name

```
    public void HandleException(Exception ex, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            while (ex.InnerException != null)
                ex = ex.InnerException;

            foreach (var method in new StackTrace().GetFrames())
            {
                if (method.GetMethod().Name == caller)
                {
                    caller = $"{method.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name}.{caller}";
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message} Caller: {caller}()");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `System.Reflection.MethodBase` method `GetCurrentMethod`, you can find full information about the call stack using classes, etc.

Comment: How?  [`GetCurrentMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`MethodBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't seem to expose anything about the stack trace (except the current type).

Answer (score 0):

The current calling namespace which is not equal as the current namespace:

```
    var mNamespace = new StackTrace().GetFrames()?.Select(x =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return x.GetMethod().ReflectedType?.Namespace;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                }).First(x => x != new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType?.Namespace);
```