# How to capture all user actions in a WPF application to store them in a log file?

Tags: c#, logging, visual-studio-2013, event-handling

## Introduction

I have a WPF application with code written in C#, developed in Visual Studio 2013. This is a GUI solution and has many interdependent projects, complete with buttons, fields, menus, checkboxes and text.

## Logging user actions

My goal is to create a log file (a txt file will do) of all actions that an end user takes while using this application. Example actions could be a button-click, writing in a blank text field, (de)select a check-box, close an activity/tab, etc. I want to capture **all** such user interactions in the application UI, and have those actions stored as summarized one line descriptions of the action in a text log file.

## Possible solutions

#### Brute force method

One way to do this could be to update the event handlers of all the aforementioned elements (button, textfield, ...) with the code to write a summary of the action to append to a txt log file. For example, in an accept button click handler:

```cs
 private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // TODO: default button click handler code...

     // TODO: ...and the code to write the event to a txt log file         
 }
```

But this strategy will be very painful to accomplish, having to update each and *every* event handler (and even write event handlers for elements which don't have any currently).

#### Better way(s)

I am looking for a simpler way in which this could be achieved. Some ideas that I have are:

One way is changing the **event handler base class** (that all other event handlers inherit from?) to contain the log file writing code. This way the log file code will need to be written only once, and it will be called whenever *any* event handler is called, which is what we want (There needs to be a distinction made between a user generated events and an app generated event, which can prove difficult in case of *event chaining*. So this could be a challenge).

Another way is using some "*sniffer*" which works like a debugger and stores the stack trace of an application's methods, as the user moves through it. This would give us only a partial idea of the user's workflows.

```
    private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    private bool IsValidName(string userName)
    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    private void Close()
    ...
```

Adding a time stamp to the message would be useful...

```
    3/1/2015 18:19 private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    3/1/2015 18:19 private bool IsValidName(string userName)
    3/1/2015 18:21 private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    3/1/2015 18:21 private void Close()
    ...
```

... because, deleting the messages which have a time stamp difference from that of the previous message below a suitable threshold, would leave only the methods that were directly called by the user actions. Assuming that methods signatures are descriptive enough, this message list could work as the desired log file.

```
    3/1/2015 18:19 private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    3/1/2015 18:21 private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    ...
```

However, this will only work for elements that have event handlers associated with them. Still, it's better than the brute force method.

## Suggestion(s)?

I am having some difficulty in coming up with a way to implement these ideas. Can anyone elaborate on how they could be implemented? Or if you can come up with better ways to make the log file, please share your ideas and also how it can be developed. Thank you!

Comment: what is your definition of `ALL USER ACTIONS` what actions are truly pertinent to your solution ? there are many ways to log things in an application but you need to narrow down as well as Identify the ones that will be more meaningful in regards to tracking / debugging errors, etc..

Comment: If you read the second line in Logging user actions, I have given example user actions that I want captured. This will give you an idea of what information I want to store in my log file: all user interactions with the application.

Comment: are you familiar with `StackTrace or Reflection` take a look here for examples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367830/how-to-find-full-name-of-calling-method-c-sharp

Comment: sounds like a good case for postsharp https://www.postsharp.net/ you can get the post compiler to add the loging decoration to all your classes

Comment: Postsharp has excellent [logging](https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging) capabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Microsoft UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx) to see if it meets your needs. It includes the ability to be notified of [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748252.aspx), which looks like what you want.

Answer (score 4):

So, it's WPF; and if correctly written, it's also MVVM. Then you can **decorate** your viewmodels and capture all the bindings that change. The below example will demonstrate this. For button clicks, you can use the similar approach, except you will be intercepting the `ICommand` instances and listening to their events.

### Example

For example, let's say you have your regular viewmodel defined (pseudo code) that has two-way property called `SimpleProperty`:

```
class SimpleViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public string SimpleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

To add logging, define a decorator as shown below (again pseudo code):

```
class LoggerViewModel : IViewModel
{
    private readonly IViewModel _originalVM;
    private readonly static Logger _logger = new Logger(); 

    public LoggerViewModel(IViewModel originalVM) 
    {
        _originalVM = originalVM;
    }

    public string SimpleProperty 
    {
        get 
        {
            _logger.Log("Page requested SimplePriperty and value is " + _originalVM.SimpleProperty);
            return _originalVM.SimpleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _logger.Log("Page changed SimpleProperty and value is " + _originalVM.SimpleProperty);
            _originalVM.SimpleProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, the IViewModel interface looks like this:

```
interface IViewModel
{
    string SimpleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this pattern is easily implemented generically by some of the dynamic features of the framework.  Implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider and construct a DynamicMetaObject type that intercepts calls in order to log them.  Create it once, use it everywhere you bind, done.

Comment: It's just an implementation detail. Point is to decorate it with something that intercepts changes.

Comment: Yes, an implementation detail... until you have to do it for twenty VMs, each with thirty properties :)

Comment: I believe every answer should be "for dummies", and every implementation should be "for experts". What is you see above is an answer, and it serves the purpose. Can it be extended? - yes. Is your suggestion the only one I can find? - no. Done.

Comment: How would the decorator be used?

Comment: Since my decorator needs initialization through its constructor, it could be registered inside the corresponding view's constructor (code-behind), by using DataContext property.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple and straightforward way would be intercepting all of your application's windows messages and storing the information you need for the messages you need.

The most straightforward way to achieve this is to make a "message filter" ([Application.AddMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). It looks something like this:

```
public class GlobalMessageLogger : IMessageFilter{

    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message message){
        if (message.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            //Log message
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new GlobalMessageLogger());
```

You can use the [`Message` struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) members (of the `message` parameter) to get more info on a specific message. You'd have to read up on specific Windows messages, their codes (stored in the `Msg` param), and their `wParam` and `lParam` values. To find out what part of your application sent a specific message, you can use the `HWnd` property.

This is a pretty low-level approach, but it gives you great flexibility (you're not limited to UI elements that actually have event handlers), and makes changes for logging purposes hihgly localized.

Comment: This question is about WPF and your solution is for Windows Forms? Does this work in WPF or is there an equivalent?