# How to access the NUnit test name programmatically?

Tags: nunit, naming

Is there some global state somewhere that I can access the currently-running test name?

I have tests which output files into a directory and read them back in. I'd like each test to create a directory to play in and then clean up after itself, and I don't want to push that name in (I'd have to make it unique, and then make sure each test keeps it unique; ew). I could use a GUID, but I'd like helper methods to be able to assume "this is the place where test files should be stored" without having to push that GUID around to them. Again, this augers for a global state somewhere.

Basically, I want a call like `TestRunner.Current.CurrentTest.Name`. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I haven't upgraded to 2.5.7 yet myself, but it includes a `TestContext` class that seems to provide just what you're looking for: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5.7

Comment: This works great. I use a Regex to strip out any characters that don't work in a directory name, and it's all good. Thanks!

Comment: To use it in code, get the TestContext by calling the static CurrentContext method.  So, for example:  TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name

Comment: Updated documentation for NUnit 3: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext

Answer (score 47):

(Assuming c#)

```
NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name
```

or

```
NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName
```

or if you are really lazy and aren't driving your tests with TestCaseSource (thanks @aolszowka):

```
this.GetType().ToString()
```

Comment: This was originally suggested to use 

    this.GetType().ToString()

If you were lazy; however this does not work for TestCaseSource driven tests, you must use one of the two overloads from TestContext to work in all scenarios.

Comment: @aolszowka why did you remove the line instead of adding that information in your edit?

Comment: @aolszowka but that's the opposite to what you've done. You've removed information in the post and replaced it in your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming one method per Test, in your NUnit code, you can use reflection to get the method name from the stacktrace.

If you write a helper method in your NUnit code called by other methods to do this file logging, you can use this syntax to check for the *previous method*:

```
string MethodName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
```

See the answers to [question 44153, "Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method) for more details.

Comment: This won't handle [TestCase] methods that are called multiple times, but it's close enough to get you the rep.

Answer (score 1):

If we are using TestCaseSource tag then above solutions might not give correct answer

Try using TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName

Follow the below example

```
namespace NunitTests
{
public class Class1
{

static List<TestData> Data = new List<TestData>()
        {
            new TestData()
            {
                ...
            }
        };

[Test]
        [TestCaseSource(nameof(TenMBInstance))]
        public void TestCase(TestData value)
        {
            TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name; //TestCase(NunitTests..TestData) 
            TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName; //TestCase
        }
}
}
```