# Extract method name from expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, expression-trees

I am trying to implement the following pattern function:

```
MethodInfo GetMethod(      
  Expression<Func<TTarget, EventHandler<TEventArgs>>> method)
```

I can provide an instance of TTarget if required

The desired usage is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var methodInfo = GetMethod<Program, EventArgs>(t => t.Method);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
}

private void Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethod(TTarget target, Expression<Func<TTarget, EventHandler<TEventArgs>>> method)
{
  var lambda = method as LambdaExpression;
  var body = lambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
  var call = body.Operand as MethodCallExpression;
  var mInfo = call.Method as MethodInfo;

  Console.WriteLine(mInfo);

  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It prints out:

`System.Delegate CreateDelegate(System.Type, System.Object, System.Reflection.Met
hodInfo)`

Comment: It might be helpful to tag the question with the programming language you are using. It looks like C# but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're half way there.
Look at the code below

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var program = new Program();
    var methodInfo = GetMethod<Program, EventArgs>(()=> program.Method);
    Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
}
```

And use the following code to get the method name.

```
static MethodInfo GetMethod<TTarget, TEventArgs>(Expression<Func<EventHandler<TEventArgs>>> method) where TEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    var convert = method.Body as UnaryExpression;
    var methodCall = (convert.Operand as MethodCallExpression);
    if (methodCall != null && methodCall.Arguments.Count>2 && methodCall.Arguments[2] is ConstantExpression)
    {
        var methodInfo = (methodCall.Arguments[2]as ConstantExpression).Value as MethodInfo;
        return methodInfo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I hope this answers your question.