# Is it possible to create a general method which with the input of a lambda expression can return the method name as a String?

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to create a which takes a lambda expression of a method call in, and returns the name of the method (without namespace) as a string back. I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014747/extract-method-name-from-expression-tree) which solves the question in VB.NET for `Func<TTarget, EventHandler<TEventArgs>>`, but I want to be able to do it for any `Func` or `Action` with any number of parameters. Is it possible to create a single method by using [System.Linq.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) derivates of it which accomplishes this?

I've been struggling for half an hour with [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9015598/507339) but I can't even get it to compile.

I've also this solution, but I'm getting an invalid cast exception at runtime:

```
public static String NameOfMethod(Expression<Action> exp)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)(Object)exp).Method.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exp` is a `LambdaExpression` so you need to cast the body:

```
return ((MethodCallExpression)exp.Body).Method.Name;
```