# Which Method Am I In?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, methods

I am aiming to add some #if DEBUG to my methods however I don't want to edit the code I copy and Paste into each method.

Is there a generic piece of code like this:

```
void DoSomething()
            {
#if Debug
            Log("Now In " + MethodName);
#endif
            }
```

Where MethodName is populated to equal DoSomething, or whichever Method called the Log?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.5 you can use the [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
public static GetCallerMemberName([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
{
    return caller;
}
```

Note that when calling this method you don't need to pass anything as an argument - the C# compiler does the work for you. This also means that you avoid performing reflection at runtime, which makes this method much faster.

Usage:

```
void DoSomething()
{
#if Debug
    Log("Now In " + GetCallerMemberName()); // Logs "Now in DoSomething"
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```