# Using nameof to get name of current method

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-6.0, nameof

Have browsed, searched and hoped but cannot find a straight answer.

*Is there anyway in C# 6.0 to get the current method name using `nameof` withouth specifying the method name?*

I am adding my test results to a dictionary like this:

```
Results.Add(nameof(Process_AddingTwoConsents_ThreeExpectedRowsAreWrittenToStream), result);
```

I would prefer if I would not have to specify the method name explicitly so I can copy+paste the line, a non-working example:

```
Results.Add(nameof(this.GetExecutingMethod()), result);
```

If possible I do not want to use Reflection.

**UPDATE**

This is not (as suggested) a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method). I am asking if is explicitly possible to make use of `nameof` without(!) reflection to get the current method name.

Comment: And why don´t you use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method?

Comment: You can use `StackTrace` to get such info, but this is slow. To achieve something automatic you can use code-generation (e.g. a tool which run before compiler and replaces something with something else) or AOP (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25803/1997232)).

Comment: Wouldn't this do it?
`System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name`

Comment: He Literally said "without using reflection"

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can't use `nameof` to achieve that, but how about this workaround:

**The below uses no direct reflection (just like `nameof`) and no explicit method name.**

```
Results.Add(GetCaller(), result);

public static string GetCaller([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
{
    return caller;
}
```

`GetCaller` returns the name of any method that calls it.

Comment: How does this help? You need the caller of the executing method, not the caller of `GetCaller`; unless you are proposing adding an optional parameter to *all* potentially callable methods in order to make this work which is, frankly, hideous.

Comment: @InBetween The OP stated `"get the current method name"` . This does exactly what he stated ! You only need one `GetCaller` method that you can call from anywhere to get the current executing method name.

Comment: I would recommend using `caller = null` since this is more obvious imo. Its also the example from MS istelf and R#

Comment: Wish this had been around from the beginning... :-(

Comment: this works greatly. The problem with nameof(method) is beyound simple copy-paste issues. When you use nameof(method) for logging, for example, visual studio counts 1 reference/caller in method for each nameof(method) you use. It becomes hard to identify if a method is not called by any other and can be safelly deleted

Answer (score 15):

Building on user3185569's great answer:

```
public static string GetMethodName(this object type, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
{
    return type.GetType().FullName + "." + caller;
}
```

Results in you being able to call `this.GetMethodName()` anywhere to return the fully qualified method name.

Comment: How I call in ***static method*** ? not valid `this`

Comment: @Kiquenet  Make an overload of GetMethodName() that doesn't include the `type` parameter, and call it like any other static method.  e.g. `Util.GetMethodName();`

Answer (score 2):

Same as others, but some variation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the caller method name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <param name="caller"></param>
    /// <param name="fullName">if true returns the fully qualified name of the type, including its namespace but not its assembly.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetMethodName(this object type, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null, bool fullName = false)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        var name = fullName ? type.GetType().FullName : type.GetType().Name;
        return $"{name}.{caller}()";
    }
```

Allows to call it like this:

```
Log.Debug($"Enter {this.GetMethodName()}...");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the name of the current method into the Results List then you may use this :

```
StackTrace sTrace= new StackTrace();
StackFrame sFrame= sTrace.GetFrame(0);
MethodBase currentMethodName = sFrame.GetMethod();
Results.Add(currentMethodName.Name, result);
```

Or you can use,

```
Results.Add(new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, result);
```

Comment: Note that is probably not reliable, since the method might be inlined. I would also expect it to be pretty slow.

Comment: In general you should never use these classes in production code

Comment: `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()` will do this more easily (and probably more quickly)