# Get full name of parameter (namespace, class, method and name) c#

Tags: c#, string, class, reflection, namespaces

How would I get the namespace, class, method and name of a parameter or variable. For example:

```
namespace TheNamespace
{
    class Theclass
    {
        void Thing()
        {
            string thevariable = "";
            string b = thevariable.GetFullName();
            // b would be equal to TheNamespace.Theclass.Thing.thevariable
        }
    }

}
```

How would I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters and variables don't have namespace/class name so to get string you are looking for you simply combine [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method) and [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter):

```
string b = 
       System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "." + 
       nameof(thevariable);
```